# ‘IonList’ is not assignable to parameter of type ‘HTMLIonItemSlidingElement ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this issue that keeps showing up each time i run the below command

```
ionic cordova build android --profile prod --release --prod
```

[image: ERROR DISPLAYED]

```js
//ts file code
@ViewChild('slidingItem', { static: true }) devotionList: IonList;


async addPost(slidingItem: HTMLIonItemSlidingElement,post: any) {
// code goes here 
}
```

```html
 //html page
<ion-row class="ion-align-items-stretch" #postList [hidden]="shownSessions === 0">
      <ion-col size="12" size-md="6" *ngFor="let post of posts" [hidden]="post.hide">
        <!-- post item -->
        <ion-item-sliding #slidingItem>
          <div>
            <ion-item detail lines="inset" routerLink="/single-post/{{post.id}}">
              <ion-text>
                <h4 class="devotion-topic">
                  {{post.title}}
                </h4>
                <p class="devotion-date">
                  {{post.dateCreated | date}}
                  <!-- {{post.date}}  -->
                </p>
                <p class="devotion-excerpt">
                  {{post.excerpt}}
                </p>
              </ion-text>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options>
              <ion-item-option (click)="addpost(slidingItem, post)" *ngIf="segment === 'all'">
                Favorite
              </ion-item-option>
              <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="removePost(slidingItem, post, 'Remove Favorite')"
                *ngIf="segment === 'favorites'">
                Remove
              </ion-item-option>
            </ion-item-options>
          </div>
        </ion-item-sliding>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

i don't have an idea of what i am doing wrong. based on my research ionlist extends the HTMLIonItemSlidingElement

ionic forum link for the same question

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionlist-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-htmlionitemslidingelement/178131

Answer (score 0):

I actually learned from the ionic community slack forum what i was doing wrong 
I changed the below code and my command ran successfully

```
@ViewChild('slidingItem', { static: true }) devotionList: IonList;
```

> to

```
@ViewChild('slidingItem', { static: true }) devotionList: IonItemSliding;
```

and

```
async addPost(slidingItem: HTMLIonItemSlidingElement,post: any) {// code goes here}
```

> To

```
async addPost(slidingItem: IonItemSliding,post: any) {// code goes here}
```

I was actually referencing the wrong type.